# Getting the output of print representation in gdb, and using it as a string with gdb's printf?

Tags: string, gdb

There is a difference in using `print` and `printf` commands in GDB: `print` may print related fields if the argument is an object, while `printf` strictly expects format specifiers and C-style strings.

What I'd like to do, is to "get" the output of a `gdb` `print` expression, and use it as a string data with a `%s` format specifier. Usually, that doesn't work - with this `test.cpp` program:

```
// g++ --std=c++11 -g test.cpp -o test.exe

#include <iostream>
#include <set>

std::string aa; // just to have reference to std::string

int main()
{
  std::set<std::string> my_set;
  my_set.insert("AA");
  my_set.insert("BB");
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I can get output like this:

```
$ gdb --args ./test.exe
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
...
Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:13
13    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
(gdb) p my_set
$1 = std::set with 2 elements = {[0] = "AA", [1] = "BB"}
(gdb) p *my_set
No symbol "operator*" in current context.
(gdb) p my_set->begin()
Cannot resolve method std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::begin to any overloaded instance
```

... but I cannot just use `my_set` as argument of `printf`, since there a char array would be expected:

```
(gdb) printf "it is: '%s'\n", my_set
it is: 'Value can't be converted to integer.
```

So, is it possible to somehow obtain the representation of an object of `print` as a string, to use it as an argument of `printf`? Assuming pseudocode function `print_repr()`, I'd like to achieve this:

```
(gdb) printf "it is: '%s'\n", print_repr(my_set)
it is: '= std::set with 2 elements = {[0] = "AA", [1] = "BB"}'
```

... and also would like the same to function for errors, say:

```
(gdb) printf "it is: '%s'\n", print_repr(*my_set)
it is: 'No symbol "operator*" in current context.'
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this using @TomTromey's pointers, but it wasn't exactly trivial, so I'm posting this as an answer, tested on gdb 7.7.1. First, I added this to my `~/.gdbinit` file:

```python
python
# https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API
# https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Functions-In-Python.html
class Greet (gdb.Function):
  """Return string to greet someone.
  Takes a name as argument."""
  def __init__ (self):
    super (Greet, self).__init__ ("greet")
  def invoke (self, name):
    return "Hello, %s!" % name.string ()
Greet() # instantiate; then call in gdb: p $greet("myname")

#(gdb) python gdb.execute("p 22")
#$2 = 22

class Strp (gdb.Function):
  """Get a representation of gdb's printout as string
  Argument: the gdb command as string."""
  def __init__ (self):
    super (Strp, self).__init__ ("strp")
  def invoke (self, incmd):
    incmds = str(incmd)
    #print("is",incmds)
    # strip quotes
    if (incmds[0] == incmds[-1]) and incmds.startswith(("'", '"')):
      incmds = incmds[1:-1]
    rets=""
    try:
      rets += gdb.execute(incmds, from_tty=True, to_string=True)
    except Exception as e:
      rets += "Exception: {0}".format(e)
    #print("ret",ret)
    return rets
Strp() # instantiate; then call in gdb: p $strp("p 22")
# quotes end up in arg string, so by default getting Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> Undefined command: "".  Try "help".: ... but then, if call WITHOUT quotes p $strp(p aa), gdb may interpret "p" as symbol (which doesn't exist) before it is sent as arg to python; therefore, use quotes, then strip them
end
```

Then, I can do in `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p $strp("x 22")
$1 = "Exception: Cannot access memory at address 0x16"
(gdb) p $strp("p 22")
$3 = "$2 = 22\n"
(gdb) p $strp("p aa")
$4 = "Exception: No symbol \"aa\" in current context."
(gdb) printf "%s\n", $strp("p 22")
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

So, the regular `gdb` `p`rint does not need a process, however `printf` does - so after setting a breakpoint, and `r`unning the program/process in `gdb`, finally one can use both the Python function and `printf` at the prompt:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at /...:17
17  int main( ){
(gdb) printf "%s\n", "aa"
aa
(gdb) printf "%s\n", $strp("p 22")
$12 = 22

(gdb) printf "%s\n", $strp("x 22")
Exception: Cannot access memory at address 0x16
(gdb) printf "%s\n", $strp("p aa")
Exception: No symbol "aa" in current context.
(gdb) printf "%s -- %s\n", $strp("p aa"), $strp("p 22")
Exception: No symbol "aa" in current context. -- $13 = 22
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me say that there's no really good reason, IMO, that gdb can't do this via a special `printf` substitution.  Why not?  The whole thing is under gdb's control

That said, is possible, sort of, using the gdb CLI, however it is pretty difficult.  You have to do a funny dance involving `set logging`, then use `shell` to rewrite the output file to a gdb script, then `source` it.  Possible, but gross.

It's somewhat simpler with Python.  You can write a convenience function in Python that returns the value as a string.  Then you can just write something like:

```
(gdb) printf "%s", $_print_repr(whatever)
```

The gdb manual has a section on writing new convenience functions.  It is pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks for that, @TomTromey - this answers it, so I'm accepting, although I haven't tried it yet; cheers!

Comment: I forgot to mention -- another option for formatted output in gdb is the `output` command.  This works like `print` but doesn't affect the value history.  So, you can also mix `printf` and `output` calls to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot do this without jumping through heroic means:

```
(gdb) printf "it is: '%s'\n", my_set
it is: 'Value can't be converted to integer.
```

You *can* break it down into more than one step.  Perhaps not ideal, but it doesn't require creating a bunch of Python wrapper goo.

```
printf "it is: '"
output my_set
printf "'\n"
```

This of course is a little less useful interactively, but is perfectly reasonable in a custom-defined GDB command.  This is probably the genesis of your question, as `printf`ing to yourself in the interactive debugger is a little strange, but not wrong of course.