# Does gdb have dprintf that prints structures?

Tags: gdb

gdb has [dprintf](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dynamic-Printf.html), which works a follows:

The following:

```
$ dprintf fib, "n is %d\n", n
```

Is a shortcut for:

```
$ break fib
$ commands
silent
printf "n is %d\n", n
cont
end
```

But usually I find `p` more useful than `printf`. Among other things, it supports structures (and does symbolic printing of constants). In other words, instead of `printf "n is %d\n"` I want to do `p n`.

Is there any convenience command for doing this?

Comment: I think the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744646/getting-the-output-of-print-representation-in-gdb-and-using-it-as-a-string-with) applies here.

Comment: @Tom Tromey: Thanks, I'll keep a watch on that question. Another way to solve *my* question is to `define` a command similar to `dprintf` in ~/.gdbinit. I haven't yet figured out how to do it. I'll post an answer when I do.

Comment: It can only sort of be done, the difficulty being that the `continue` in the commands will interfere with `next`ing.  This is also solvable from Python.